# The random error term is assumed to follow the normal distribution with a mean of 0 in linear regression at each point in x axis

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model

while going through http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Simple_Linear_Regression_Analysis
[image]

They have plotted a normal distribution at X=65 and X=90 and say that error term follow a normal distribution , since linear regression is a function that out puts only one value for a given X , how did they plot the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the sample with the population. There's a population of possible response-values at any given $x$ (hence the conditional distribution [$Y|x$]), but in your sample you might only observe a single $y$-value at that specific $x$. Or you might observe two values, or 200 values (in which case the ECDF of the sample y's at that x-value might then start to look something like the population cdf there)

Answer (score 0):

For a linear regression you *assume* that the data come from a normal distribution, whose mean is a function of the predictor:
$$y \sim N(\mu=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x, \sigma)$$
After fitting (using maximum likelihood), you get estimates for the $\beta$s (typically indicated by adding the hat ^: $\hat{\beta}_1$) and for $\hat{\sigma}$. The figure plots the normal distribution using this estimated $\hat{\sigma}$, with the mean at the expected value for $\mu = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 \cdot 65$ and 90, respectively.

It is more common (but less generalisable) to write this as $y_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i$ (or its vector equivalent). In this case, we assume $\varepsilon$ to be normally distributed: $\varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma)$, i.e. centred on the expected value for a given $x_i, E(y_i | x_i) = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i$.

That's what the text in the figure tries to say. Personally, I like to see the hat for estimated values (or move from Greek to Latin: $\hat{\beta} = b, \hat{\sigma}=s$); and I assume that the meaning of $\varepsilon$ is explained in the text. (I don't like the way $\varepsilon_{90}$ suggests that for $x=90$ $\varepsilon$ would always be one specific value; which of course it would not: that's why the author drew the distribution).